# Find buttons (onclick) and click all of them

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have trouble. Im using java and webdriver. I want to go http://demo.opencart.com/, find "ipod", 
I have 4 results, and I want to compare them (by clicking under each button "compare"), but there are 2 problem.

1. how to click on compare (there are onclick)

   `<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="compare.add('48');" data-original-title="Compare this Product"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></butto`n>
2. how to compare all my search results?

Comment: do you have any code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can surely use the java backend to save the results in variables and compare they. Also, if you click in the button that you show us, you will call the compare js method

Comment: But, how to click on it? I thing I cant use css or xpath becouse there are 4 results of searching, and i have to click all of them

Comment: By 'compare', surely you want to assert against and validate the results (in code) rather than just clicking a button that could work / not work / give bad results...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    package pkYourPackage;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


    // http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=24

    public class OpenCart_StackOverflow {
        static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/.....put_ path/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=24");
            try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception e){}

            List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(@data-original-title,'Compare this')]/i"));
            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
                list.get(i).click();

                try{Thread.sleep(1500);}catch(Exception e){}

            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1500);}catch(Exception e){}

            // click on 'product comparison' to compare
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'product comparison')]")));
            try{Thread.sleep(10000);}catch(Exception e){}
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I know it's only demo code, but all those hardcoded waits are an absolute killer - especially if a newbie copies and pastes this code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I made sth like this:

```
 public void count(){

        List <WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-original-title='Compare this Product']"));

    for(WebElement buttons: button){
        buttons.click();
    }
```

Is it a good  solution? For sure its much shorter than Kumar's solution, and it works

Comment: What should I assert in this part? Its a task to get a job, so I want to make best solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-original-title='Compare this Product']"));
```

both of the below code works same way, either use
this :

```
for(WebElement buttons: button){
    buttons.click();
}
```

or use this :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < button.size() ; i++)
{
    button.get(i).click();
}
```